# Whitelabel Error Page Error after deployed on server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a project using spring boot framework.
 
I Got this error after the deployment on server, But it is running fine on localhost.

**Whitelabel Error Page** 
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Apr 30 19:14:00 GMT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/view/sign-in.jsp

> **this is my application.properties file**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.thymeleaf.view-names=html/*

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
```

Comment: did you package your application as WAR? and what server are you using?

Comment: How do you deploy it? With docker or just execute the jar/war?

Comment: Keep in mind That you have to pack it as war file to provide static content like views

Comment: I just executed jar file?

Comment: you need to provide us more information about your problem so we can help you. maybe show us the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved when I add `<packaging>war</packaging>` in my project to create war file as suggested by [medTech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9326543/medtech).